# Reverse order of Y axis in C3 line chart

Tags: c3.js

Is it possible to set y axis values in reverse order(100-0)? Something like this

[image]

This is basically the rank chart, If the rank goes down chart will go up. Here is the code.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: https://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-y-inverted

Comment: Great @mgraham! It works fine, Thank you.